# Bash HTML for version 3.2?

Tags: bash, manpage

I've been using the bash manual from this [link](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html)

but it is for ver 4.2 and I'm using 3.2.  Does anyone know where to find an HTML for 3.2?

Comment: Does your installed version of bash not have a man page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to use `man(1)`, you can use a tool such as `man2html` to transform your bash's manual page into HTML.

Otherwise, just: `man bash`.

Comment: I find it very hard to search man bash.  If you want to look up something like the "if" statement you get over 100 hits.  Do you know some clever way to use man more effectively?

Comment: You're right, a very long manual can be pretty hard to read on a single page, without bookmarks. You could try `info bash` instead, since it seems better organized.

Comment: You can always use regexp while searching in man; if you are looking for "for loops" you can do `/^ *for .*` and you'll go stright to for loops section. I know that in other cases it may be more difficult or you may need to know how sections are called, ie: `/^ *brace expansion`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like how the man page is structured, perhaps the GNU project's HTML rendition of the info page suits you better. But the gnu.org site only shows the latest version. Wayback Machine to the rescue!

http://wayback.archive.org/web/20071220154123/http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html